# Python Keypressing - Printing list only when value changes

Tags: python, list, keypress

I'm trying to do the following thing:

Store keypress state in a list (False or True values) then if I press or unpress some key the list will be printed only if it's content changes and only once. (Keypress in this case)

I tried checking W A S D keys:

```
import keyboard

# List initializing
list = [False, False, False, False]
previous_list = [False, False, False, False]


while True:
     list[0] = keyboard.is_pressed("w")
     list[1] = keyboard.is_pressed("a")
     list[2] = keyboard.is_pressed("s")
     list[3] = keyboard.is_pressed("d")

     if list != previous_list:
         print(list)
         previous_list = list
```

Can you guys help me discovering why isn't it working ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all don't name variables with reserved keywords. as you know `list` is a reserved keyword. Now what is the problem in your case, the main problem is assigning lists, you are using `=` that is assigning also references and they are becoming the same arrays looking the same pointer so they will be equal after that. when you change `list` it will change `previous_list` too. The fix is simple you need to copy lists and let us also rename your variable.

```py
import keyboard

# List initializing
ls = [False, False, False, False]
previous_list = [False, False, False, False]


while True:
     ls[0] = keyboard.is_pressed("w")
     ls[1] = keyboard.is_pressed("a")
     ls[2] = keyboard.is_pressed("s")
     ls[3] = keyboard.is_pressed("d")

     if ls != previous_list:
         print(ls)
         previous_list = ls.copy()
         # previous_list = ls[:]
         # previous_list = list(ls)
```

so by using `copy()` we are making a copy of the original list, you can also use `previous_list = ls[:]`, or `previous_list = list(ls)`

Comment: Thank you very much Demetre, very well explained. I tried this way and worked like a charm. I'm not able yet to upvote your answer because i'm new here, stackoverflow rules.

Comment: @Jonathan Glad, it helped you. Please Upvote or Accept the solution whenever you can, it will help me too. Thanks a lot